# Can Angular CLI be configured to live-reload on save only?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Currently I use the `--live-reload` option of [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) so the application reloads automatically on change. However, more often than not, the application is reloaded before the file being edited is syntactically correct.

```sh
# Reload the page on change, using live-reload.
ng serve --live-reload true
```

I've looked through the options for the [serve command](https://angular.io/cli/serve), but it seems there is no way to rebuild on save, then "live" reload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default action is to live reload on save, it is more likely that your editor/IDE is auto saving on every change, you should be able to change this behavior in your editors settings.

Comment: That was it. For some reason VSCode was configured to auto-save; https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save